# how to bend/transform own image

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, image, transforms

I'm new to blender. I don't know how to bend (transform) my png. I know how to do it with Objects like the monkey (found tutorial) but I don't know how to transform/bend my image into a something like a crown. Can please somebody help me? I tried it for 4 Days now and I checkt every tutorial. A friend showed it to me in Maya and it looked so easy but I can't do it on my own with blender.

Comment: Can you provide some more information please? are you trying to transform a UV texture? or an image in compositor?

Comment: Hello, as Zophiekat says we lack information on what you want to do, maybe show what Maya is doing, is your png supposed to remain a flat object or do you want an extrusion, etc?

Comment: hi, guys I can't believe you two answered me that fast. Thanks. I have a png and its just like a stripe made out of leaves. I want to turn it into a crown. I need to export it in DAE so I can put it into Sparks and make a filter out of it. My Problem is, that I just don't know how to transform the Stripe into a crown. There were many tutorials but not one of them was right for me. I know hoe to transform that (Mash)monkey now but not how to transform (curve) my stripe.

Comment: Try posting some images of what you've got, and what you are trying to achieve. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1):

We lack informations, but if your image has a transparent background, you can map it on a cylinder like that:

[image]

If you're using Eevee, don't forget to choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* in the *Material > Settings* in order to have transparency.